# Is it possible to have methods in a NUnit test fixture resemble BDD style Given, When, Then?

Tags: c#, nunit, bdd

I would like my test fixture to look like this:

```
public class Adding_two_and_three
{
    [Given]
    public void Two_and_three()
    {
         ....
    }
    [When]
    public void Adding_Them()
    {
        ...
    }
    [Then]
    public void Result_should_be(5)
    {
        ...
    }
```

`Given` and `Then` can be realized using the `TestFixtureSetUp` and `Test` attributes respectively. The argument to the `Then`-method can also be accomplished using the `Values`attribute. But is there anyway to have the `When`-method using NUnit? Note also that I want to be able to have more than one `Then`methods and therefore the `When`method must only execute once.

Comment: Why not to use something like Specflow?

Comment: I would recommend using a framework with this built in already instead of forcing it through NUnit. I recommend Machine.Specifications.

Comment: I could use another framework in normal circumstances but this is not an option at my current location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized one can use the constructor as the `Given`, `TestFixtureSetUp` as `When` and `Test` as `Then`:

```
public class Adding_two_and_three
{
   [Given]
   public Adding_two_and_three()
   {
     ....
   }

   [When]
   public void Adding_Them()
   {
     ...
   }

   [Then]
   public void Result_should_be(5)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

This solves the problem but would put constraints on naming the `Given` which is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This *kind of* works, but I'd look to a different framework before attempting this.

I have written some tests in a similar way to the G/W/T method in NUnit, but it looked more like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Adding_two_and_three
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Given_two_and_three()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Two_and_three()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [Test]
    public void Result_should_be(int expected = 5)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You are likely to run into many drawbacks to this method over traditional G/W/T test fixtures, but if this works for you, great! :)

Comment: This would be an option if I only had one Test method but I would like to have several and therefore the When-method has to execute only once. Should've stated this in the question, I'll edit my question. Cheers.